# How to run a function for specific period of time in 24 hrs in Background Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

For example I want to run an infinite for loop in background but only for 4 hrs in 24 hrs. So, I want to add a restriction.
Note: Can't use SharedPreference to store anything because by clear data user can reset time is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You want [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), but an infinite loop is going to get your service killed pretty quickly by the OS. Maybe you could rethink your requirements.

Comment: So, what can I use as alternative? I need something which can keep refreshing the url and when it get response take it to next step.

Comment: Use a WorkManager, and configure the conditions you want it to run under (e.g. every 2 hours, every 30m, etc).